# Cannot sort event of current days in FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I'm using FullCalendar it has days event like Morning, Aftenoon, Evening, Night
Right now i'm getting Evening first then Morning or night. But i want to sort 
it in this format Morning, Afternoon, Evening, Night.
I'm using FulCalenday v3.10.0.